# Opening and accessing a pop up window in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

Hi I need to know how to access contents of a pop up window in chrome extension.Presently I have set my website as chrome extension.What I need is that when I install the extension a pop up window should be opened asking for username and password.When the user enters his username and password it should gets stored in a local Storage.Currently I am able to open a pop up window.But I don't know how to store the name which the user enters as username.Anyone please help me.I can't figure out how to do it.
Here is manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Calpine Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Log on to calpinemate",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
},
"permissions": [

   "*://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php",
   "alarms",
    "notifications"
     ],
        "web_accessible_resources": [
        "/icon_128.png"]

      }
```

Here is background.js

```
    var myNotificationID = null;

    var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;



      function getGmailUrl() {

        return "http://calpinemate.com/";

            }


         function isGmailUrl(url) {

          return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;

         }





       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {


          chrome.tabs.query({

           url: "http://calpinemate.com/*",

         currentWindow: true
            },
         function(tabs) {

       if (tabs.length > 0) {

       var tab = tabs[0];

       console.log("Found (at least one) Gmail tab: " + tab.url);

       console.log("Focusing and refreshing count...");

       chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });

       updateIcon();

        }
      else {

      console.log("Could not find Gmail tab. Creating one...");

       chrome.tabs.create({ url: getGmailUrl() });

       updateIcon();

       }
      });

    });



       function onInit() {

        console.log('onInit');


        updateIcon();

       if (!oldChromeVersion) {

         chrome.alarms.create('watchdog', {periodInMinutes:5});

           }

         }




        function onAlarm(alarm) {

       console.log('Got alarm', alarm);

        if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {

        onWatchdog();

          } 
       else {

        updateIcon();

        }

           }


      function onWatchdog() {

      chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {

       if (alarm) {

      console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');

    } 
     else {
      console.log('Refresh alarm doesn\'t exist!? ' +
              'Refreshing now and rescheduling.');

        updateIcon();

     }
       });

        } 


       if (oldChromeVersion) {

        updateIcon();

         onInit();

        } 

       else {

          chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);

          chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);

             }




            function updateIcon(){


         var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

         req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

       if (req.readyState == 4) {

       if (req.status == 200) {


       var item=req.responseText;


       if(item==1){

        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});   

         }

      else{

       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 

       chrome.notifications.create(
        'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/icon_128.png',
       title: 'Calpinemate',
        message: 'Hello calpiner',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
           );


     chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId, btnIdx) {
    if (notifId === myNotificationID) {
    if (btnIdx === 0) {
        window.open("http://www.calpinemate.com/");
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
       notification.close();
    }
    }
     });

     chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
      notification.close();
     });


    }

      } 
   else {

        // Handle the error

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }

    }

         });

            req.open("GET", "http://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php", true);

         req.send(null);

   }


  function login() {

/* First retrieve the credentials */
    chrome.storage.local.get(['username', 'password'], function(items) {
    var user = items.username;
    var pass = items.password;

    if (!user || !pass) {

        /* Missing credentials. Prompt the user. */
        chrome.windows.create({ url : "test.html" });
        return;
    }

    /* Log-in */
    // ...code that logs the user in
      });
      }
```

Here is test.html

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function log(){
            var uname=document.getElementById('name');


             document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = uname;
        }
      </script>
     </head>
   <body>
    <form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
    username : 
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username"/><br><br>
    password :
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Log In" onclick="log()"/>
    <p id="pp"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

test.js

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var user  = document.querySelector('input#user');
   var pwd  = document.querySelector('input#pass');
  var form = document.querySelector('form#userinfo');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {     
    evt.preventDefault();
    var userStr = user.value; 
    var pwdStr = pwd.value;
   if ((userStr.length === 0) || (passStr.length === 0)) {
        alert('Please, specify both Username and Password !');
        return;
    }
   chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
     bgPage.login(userStr,pwdStr); });
    window.close();


   }); 

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the **[Content Security Policy (CSP)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)**, inline scripts won't be executed. You should move the code and the event bindings to an external JS file and use the **[chrome.storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)** to store the username and password.

**In *test.html*:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="userinfo">
            <label for="user">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user" />
            <br />
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="login" value="Log In" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**In *test.js*:**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var user  = document.querySelector('input#user');
    var pass  = document.querySelector('input#pass');
    var login = document.querySelector('input#login');

    login.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var userStr = user.value;
        var passStr = pass.value;

        /* Validate input */
        if ((userStr.length === 0) || (passStr.length === 0)) {
            alert('Please, specify both Username and Password !');
            return;
        }

        /* Store the data */
        chrome.storage.local.set({
            username: userStr,
            password: passStr,
        }, function() {

            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {

                /* An error occurred. Unable to proceed. */
                // ...handle the error, e.g. inform the user
                return;
            }

            /* Do whatever youneed to, e.g. log-in the user */
            chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
                bgPage.login();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**In *background.js*:**

```
...
function login() {

    /* First retrieve the credentials */
    chrome.storage.local.get(['username', 'password'], function(items) {
        var user = items.username;
        var pass = items.password;

        if (!user || !pass) {

            /* Missing credentials. Prompt the user. */
            chrome.windows.create({ url : "test.html" });
            return;
        }

        /* Log-in */
        // ...code that logs the user in
    });
}
```

<sub>(Using `chrome.storage.sync` (instead of `.local`) will sync the data across the user's devices if (s)he enables that option from the account settings.)</sub>

---

**Please, note:**

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

Comment: Hi can you just explain where shall i write the function login()??Is it inside my onInit()?Because I am creating the window in that function.Please help me

Comment: No it is not inside `onInit`. It is a top-level function in `background.js`.

Comment: So can You please explain where I have to put inside background.js

Comment: Hey,where should I call this function?

Comment: I added the code at the end of background.js.But it is not working.Please help me.Is there any way to alert the username entered by the user in test.html?

Comment: Have you created `test.js` as indicated in my answer ? Do you get any errors in any of the console logs ?

Comment: Yes I have created,just as your code.No error is found.But I don't know where to put the code in background.js.I put it as a separate function but still the pop up window itself is not being shown.Please help me.

Comment: You are right to have it as a separate function. The popup shows up in the `onInit` function, so you have to call it or re-install the extension. (Alternatively, the popup is shown every time the `login` function is called and there are no credentials stored in `chrome.storage`.)

Comment: so where should I call the login()?Presently it is not showing any pop up window.I will update my code.Can you please check it?

Comment: Hi I have updated my background.js.Can you please check it?I couldn't figure out where I have went wrong

Comment: Sorry, can't check your background, because the indentation is too messy. But, as I already said "The popup shows up in the onInit function" <-- This is how **you** have omplemented it, so when and how to show the popup is your responsibility. My solution above addresses the problem of storing and retrieving the credentials.

Comment: Hey i n the code provided by you in test.js,when i keep the email and the password field blank and click on login it shows the alert message.And it returns to the pop up window again.when i enter both the fields again and click login button,it is stuck.Nothing is happening in the pop up window

Comment: Hi I have post my test.js.can you please check it and help me?